# Regex: match all parts with pattern up to the next occurrence

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have the following log file (with line endings):

```
[xxx] test test[xxx]foobar
more data
[xxx] more data
[xxx] other data []:foo bar
more data here
[xxx] 1234
```

I would like to retrieve all parts starting with `[xxx]` up until the next occurrence of `[xxx]`, so the result would become (`\n` indicating the newline here):

```php
$result = [
    '[xxx] test test[xxx]foobar \n more data',
    '[xxx] more data',
    '[xxx] other data []:foo bar \n more data here',
    '[xxx] 1234'
]
```

I came up with the regex `/(\[xxx\] .*)/g` but it fails to match the cases where there are multiple lines per log entry. I've tried variations like `/(\[xxx\] [\s.]*)/g` but to no avail.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. What modifiers or other syntax should I use?

Comment: `preg_match_all('~\[xxx].*(?:\R(?!\[xxx]).*)*~', $text, $matches)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any way to simplify that expression? Do I need the negative lookahead? It seems extreme for the (seemingly) simple problem.

Comment: This is the best regex you can have as it is the most efficient. The "simple" `preg_match_all('~\[xxx].*?(?=\[xxx]|\z)~s', $text, $matches)` will take much more time to find matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of

```php
preg_match_all('~\[xxx].*(?:\R(?!\[xxx]).*)*~', $text, $matches)
preg_match_all('~\[xxx].*?(?=\[xxx]|\z)~s', $text, $matches)
```

Or  - if the left hand `[xxx]` always appears at the start of a line

```php
preg_match_all('~^\[xxx].*(?:\R(?!\[xxx]).*)*~m', $text, $matches)
preg_match_all('~^\[xxx].*?(?=^\[xxx]|\z)~ms', $text, $matches)
```

The first solution ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFOZnL/1)) is preferable because it is more efficient (see [the second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFOZnL/2)).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\[xxx]` - a `[xxx]` string
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\R(?!\[xxx]).*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\R(?!\[xxx])` - a line break sequence not immediately followed with `[xxx]`
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

The `^\[xxx].*?(?=^\[xxx]|\z)` regex matches `[xxx]` at the start of a line, then any zero or more chars as few as possible, and then either a position immediately followed with `[xxx]` at the start of a line or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate php solution using `preg_split + preg_replace` with a simple regex:

```php
$data = '[xxx] test test[xxx]foobar
more data
[xxx] more data
[xxx] other data []:foo bar
more data here
[xxx] 1234';

foreach(preg_split('/^(?=\[xxx] )/m', $data) as $el) {
    echo preg_replace('/\n(?!$)/', '\\n', $el);
}
```

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/HUpkPQ)

**Output:**

```php
[xxx] test test[xxx]foobar\nmore data
[xxx] more data
[xxx] other data []:foo bar\nmore data here
[xxx] 1234
```

**Breakup:**

- `/^(?=\[xxx] )/m`: Using this regex in `preg_split` so that we split input text every time `[xxx]`  appears on line start
- `/\n(?!$)/`: Using this regex to replace `\n` from each element of split array with `\\n`